# Grid content items overflowing container

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, css-grid

I am making a grid in nextjs and css but whenever I apply the

```
display: grid;
```

in css, the items go beyond the container even though I'd have specified the maximum width. So the items do not flow over to the following row but instead just keep going further right until they exit the screen. This is how my code looks like on the nextjs playground https://codedamn.com/playground/hNlUte0UawOjB4IbKuC02.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

- Your `.cardContainer` Element should have a `grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 2fr);` because you have only 6 Cards.
- Remove `width: 300px;` from your `.card` Elements. They are grid Element and they in this case, you wont need a fix width for them.
- Remove `max-width` from the `Home_cardContainer__frLxE` because you have  set max-width for the parent (`Home_siteContainer__TSQhQ`) already.